# Angular routing takes time when using ionic native code

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-native

I am using angular version 13 and @ionic/angular version 6.0.1. When using mobile app my router.navigate() function takes longer time to react, but it works fine in browser. My issue is click event takes longer time to react in mobile app but it works fine in desktop browser.